# Powershell Regex expression to get part of a string

Tags: regex, powershell, sharepoint

I would like to take part of a string to use it elsewhere. For example, I have the following strings:

- Project XYZ is the project name - 20-12-11

I would like to get the value "XYZ is the project name" from the string. The word "Project" and character "-" before the number will always be there.

Comment: And what is your problem with that? What does NOT work? [Read more about regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7).

Comment: I need the experssion that I can use to get this result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think a [lookaround](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) regular expression would work here since "Project" and "-" are always there:

`(?<=Project ).+?(?= -)`

A lookaround can be useful for cases that deal with getting a sub string.

Explanation:

- `(?<=` = negative lookbehind
- `Project`  = starting string (including space)
- `)` = closing negative lookbehind
- `.+?` = matches anything in between
- `(?=` = positive lookahead
- `-` = ending string
- `)` = closing positive lookahead

Example in PowerShell:

```
Function GetProjectName($InputString) {
    $regExResult = $InputString | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=Project ).+?(?= -)'
    $regExResult.Matches[0].Value
}

$projectName = GetProjectName -InputString "Project XYZ is the project name - 20-12-11"
Write-Host "Result = '$($projectName)'"
```

Comment: Thank Brat. I am actually new to Regex and I would really appreciate it if you could help with a full example to better understand how to use regex with powershell.

Comment: Okay Amir, I just added an example in PowerShell. Hopefully its helpful in your situation.

Answer (score 2):

here is yet another regex version. [*grin*] it may be easier to understand since it uses somewhat basic regex patterns.

what it does ...

- defines the input string
- defines the prefix to match on
  this will keep only what comes *after* it.
- defines the suffix to match on
  this part will keep only what is *before* it.
- trigger the replace
  the part in the `()` is what will be placed into the 1st capture group.
- show what was kept

the code ...

```
$InString = 'Project XYZ is the project name - 20-12-11'
# "^" = start of string
$Prefix = '^project '
# ".+' = one or more of any character
# "$" = end of string
$Suffix = ' - .+$'

# "$1" holds the content of the 1st [and only] capture group
$OutString = $InString -replace "$Prefix(.+)$Suffix", '$1'

$OutString
```

Comment: This answer is better because it is actually PowerShell code

Comment: until your comment, i failed to notice that the Answer by `Bart` was only regex, not PoSh with regex. [*blush*]

Answer (score 0):

```
# define the input string
$str = 'Project XYZ is the project name - 20-12-11'

# use regex (-match) including the .*? regex pattern 
# this patterns means (.)any char, (*) any times, (?) maximum greed
# to capture (into brackets) the desired pattern substring
$str -match "(Project.*?is the project name)"

# show result (the first capturing group)
$matches[1]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.